# How to take user input and insert into http get request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, get, xmlhttprequest

I've been searching and can't find a solution for what I'm looking for.

I want to be able to add details to a http request that a user submits in a form.

eg:
User submits two pieces of data via a form
Then these strings of data get added to the http get request.

Is this possible with jQuery/JavaScript? If so, how?

I hope that makes sense, if it doesn't I can try wording differently.

Comment: I answered with the assumption you meant HTTP headers. If not, which details do you want to add?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Vidya by details I meant the data the user submits via a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to simply make your form's `method` be `GET` rather than `POST` (or leave the method off, as `GET` is the default):

```
<form action="/your/endpoint" method="get">
<label>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></label>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When you submit the form, the user will be redirected to `/your/endpoint` and the value they put in the `name` text box will be added to the URL as a query-string parameter. For example, if I entered my first name, I would be redirected to `/your/endpoint?name=Sean` when I clicked on the `submit` button.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

You can get the data that way and then send it through with an ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

To add some more form data before submission do this:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      //Do stuff to populate fields (hidden or not) with data
      form = $(this);
      $.post(form.attr("action"), form.serialize(), function( data ) {
        //Success callback
      });
});
```